# How to Run a Command in Git-Bash and Leave the Shell Running?

Tags: git-bash

I have asked this question on the "*Unix*" Web-Site. It went nicely, but it was off-topic, and it was closed:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/748316/how-to-run-a-command-in-git-bash-and-leave-the-shell-running

I feel that it is a good exercise and I want to post it here.

I have started from this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317837/how-to-run-bash-commands-and-leave-prompt-open

However, apparently, `bash` and `Git-Bash` are quite different.
`Git-Bash` is a wrapper that behaves differently.

I have a shortcut that starts this `Git-Bash` shell. After starting it, I want it to `source start.sh` automatically, and then to leave the shell open.

[image: The Short-Cut]

[image: The Properties of the Short-Cut]

Whatever I have tried so far did not work.

This is my `start.sh` Shell-Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The File-Editor.
alias n='"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"'

# The Build Commands.
alias gp='/c/DGSante/Git/dg-sante-new-cpms/gp.sh'

# The 'Docker' Commands.
alias dd='docker-compose down -v'
alias db='docker-compose build'
alias du='docker-compose up'
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks everyone for commenting.

This is an example of one of my attempts to solve this problem:

The shortcut starts the following one-liner:

`/c/Progra~1/Git/git-bash.exe -c 'exec /c/Progra~1/Git/git-bash.exe --cd=/c/DGSante/Git/dg-sante-new-cpms/ --init-file /c/DGSante/Git/dg-sante-new-cpms/start.sh -i'`

However, although the first `Git-Bash` interactively starts the second `Git-Bash` in the necessary working folder and uses the `start.sh` as an `init-file`, the secondary `Git-Bash` is terminated and it does not remain open.

**SOLUTION:**

Great thanks to @muru for clarifications.

The working solution looks like the following one-liner:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --cd=C:\DGSante\Git\dg-sante-new-cpms\ --init-file C:\DGSante\Git\dg-sante-new-cpms\start.sh
```

I have removed the usage of the `Git-Bash` wrapper. I am relying entirely on the `Bash` port to the `Microsoft` `Windows` Operating-System.

I absolutely agree to @Marcus Müller's comments. However, this is the only place where I have found help.

Thanks everyone.

**RESULT:**

[image: The Shell with its sourced Script]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by @muru, maybe it is a good idea to write the answer to this question here.

This does not solve the `Git-Bash` problem, however.

It is just a workaround that is based on the `Bash` port to the `Microsoft` `Windows` Operating-System.

The following one-liner *does* start the Shell, which executes the Shell-Script, and also leaves the terminal running:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --cd=C:\DGSante\Git\dg-sante-new-cpms\ --init-file C:\DGSante\Git\dg-sante-new-cpms\start.sh
```